# Null check for Map Value sObject

Tags: apex, map

I'm looking for the logical syntax to determine if a sobject is empty.

```
ACCOUNT oRecord = new ACCOUNT();
ACCOUNT oRecord1 = new ACCOUNT();

Map<Id,ACCOUNT> mCommPref = new Map<Id,ACCOUNT>();
mCommPref.put('a2r1h000000hCPMAA2', oRecord);
oRecord1 = mCommPref.get('a2r1h000000hCPMAA2'); 

system.debug('oRecord111 -->' + oRecord1);
system.debug('oRecord1 -->' + oRecord1 == null);
```

but the `oRecord1 == null` return False, Need to Return as true when there is no value in the sobject. Can you help me on this

Tried by adding Empty Object as below

```
ACCOUNT empty = new ACCOUNT();
system.debug('oRecord1 -->' + oRecord1 == empty);
```

the above code getting this error

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Account

Comment: the accounts don't have ids?

Comment: @NickCook Yes account having Id

Answer (score 1):

`oRecord1 == null` returns false because there is an instantiated Account.

Seeing as the Accounts have Ids, you should be able to use:

`oRecord1?.Id == null`

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing "null" with "empty." An empty object is an object with no values populated, while a null object is one that doesn't exist. If you want to check if it's an "empty" account, you can:

```
system.debug('oRecord1 -->' + (oRecord1 == new Account()));
```

The `==` operator checks all the populated values in two sobjects to see if they're equal.

Comment: I think you'll need to enclose the comparison in parenthesis to avoid the "comparison arguments must be compatible types" error (that, or remove the 'oRecrod1 -->' part) to do this in a debug.

Comment: @DerekF Yeah, I don't write debug statements this way anyways, so I don't think about that too much. Edited.